# Inconsistency Dequeue issues with Spring Integration with Oracle AQ

Tags: spring-integration, oracle-aq

I am using Spring integration with Oracle AQ,configuration code is as below.
    Currently with the below configuration,the service activator is not getting invoked consistently with even the dequeue was successful at oracle end, unable to trace the message after successful Dequeue with the application logs, not even single error message shown on the log. Tried  Debug,Trace and info options in the jms adaptor, but no clue from the log details. I have verified with Oracle team on enque and deque messages, but the health check reports are clearing mentioning the messages are dequeued successfully.
    Badly required your help to get rid of this inconsitency behaviour while invoking the service activator using spring

```
<int:logging-channel-adapter id="jmslogger" log-full-message="true" level="TRACE"/>

<!-- Oracle Advanced Queue Integration -->
    <bean id="jdbc4NativeJdbcExtractor"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.Jdbc4NativeJdbcExtractor"
          p:connectionType="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection" />

    <orcl:aq-jms-connection-factory
        id="oracleAqConnectionFactory"
        use-local-data-source-transaction="true"
        native-jdbc-extractor="jdbc4NativeJdbcExtractor"
        data-source="dataSource"/>

    <!-- Siebel Atlas Service Request - Oracle Advanced Queue Integration -->
    <bean id="jmsJsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter"
        p:typeIdPropertyName="javaDtoClass"
    />

    <int:channel id="submitSiebelAtlasCreateServiceRequestOutboundRequestChannel" ></int:channel>

    <int:channel id="submitSiebelAtlasCreateServiceRequestOutboundRequestEnrichedChannel" >
        <int:interceptors>
            <int:wire-tap channel="jmslogger"/>
        </int:interceptors>
    </int:channel>

    <int:channel id="createSiebelAtlasCreateServiceRequestOutboundReplyChannel" />

    <int:logging-channel-adapter id="createSiebelAtlasCreateServiceRequestOutboundReplyChannelLogger"
        channel="createSiebelAtlasCreateServiceRequestOutboundReplyChannel" />

    <int:gateway
        id="submitSiebelAtlasCreateServiceRequestMessagingService"
        service-interface="ServiceRequestOutboundGatewayMessagingService"
        default-request-channel="submitSiebelAtlasCreateServiceRequestOutboundRequestChannel"
        default-reply-channel="submitSiebelAtlasCreateServiceRequestOutboundReplyChannel" />

    <int:header-enricher input-channel="submitSiebelAtlasCreateServiceRequestOutboundRequestChannel" output-channel="submitSiebelAtlasCreateServiceRequestOutboundRequestEnrichedChannel">
        <int:correlation-id expression="payload.getRequestId()"/>
    </int:header-enricher>

    <!-- Outbound driven channel adapter, meaning messagings are being sent to / queued in AQ -->
    <int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter
        id="siebelAtlasCreateServiceRequestJmsOutboundChannelAdapter"
        destination-name="Q_NAME"
        channel="submitSiebelAtlasCreateServiceRequestOutboundRequestEnrichedChannel"
        connection-factory="oracleAqConnectionFactory"
        message-converter="jmsJsonMessageConverter"
        auto-startup="true">
    </int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:service-activator
        output-channel="createSiebelAtlasCreateServiceRequestOutboundReplyChannel"
        input-channel="createSiebelAtlasCreateServiceRequestInboundRequestChannel"
        ref="createCustomerRelationshipsSiebelAtlasServiceRequestService"
        method="create">
    </int:service-activator>

    <int:channel id="createSiebelAtlasCreateServiceRequestInboundRequestChannel">
        <int:interceptors>
            <int:wire-tap channel="jmslogger"/>
        </int:interceptors>
    </int:channel>

    <!-- Inbound message driven channel adapter, meaning messagings are being consumed / dequeued from AQ -->
    <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter connection-factory="oracleAqConnectionFactory"
                                            message-converter="jmsJsonMessageConverter"
                                            destination-name="Q_NAME"
                                            channel="createSiebelAtlasCreateServiceRequestInboundRequestChannel"
                                            acknowledge="transacted"
                                            max-concurrent-consumers="5"
                                            transaction-manager="transactionManager"
                                            auto-startup="true"
                                            concurrent-consumers="2" />
```

Comment: Most likely there is some other consumer on the queue; I have encountered situations like this many times and it always ended up with some console or test consumer was "stealing" messages. If there is nothing in the DEBUG logs then the message(s) definitely were not consumed by Spring.

Comment: Another problem might be with the channel used for the Service Activator. If it is a `DirectChannel` and you have several subscribers to it  (not only that Service Activator) they work in round-robin manner. In this way the first dequeued message goes to the Service Activator, the second to the next subscriber, the third to the third one (if any) and then after exiting subscribers loop the handling come back to the fist one and so. Again: round-robin: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_scheduling

Comment: Hi All,
I have tried to have only single consumer for the message and tried 5 messages out of which 2 messages were calling the service activator, not sure about the remaining messages.